# Converting PDF to text: remove word breaks

Tags: python, pdf, text, file-conversion

For my PhD project I am doing some corpus preparation, which mainly consists of cleaning up my text files. I have a corpus of 170 Dutch novels, most of which I have in epub format and which I can easily convert to txt format using Calibre.

The problem is that some novels are in PDF format, which include word breaks at the end of some lines. When I convert these PDF files to txt, the word breaks are still there. For instance:

De reden van alle beroering was niet moeilijk te raden. Adri-aan bleef even staan bij een gezelschap jongerejaars om te ho-ren welke uitkomst de discussie kreeg. Maar terwijl hij stond
te luisteren naar meningen over de acute kwestie Nieuw-Gui-nea, overviel hem de herinnering aan een zonovergoten mid-
dag begin september 1939 in dezelfde hal toen hij, student gene-eskunde, met jaargenoten het zojuist ontketende Duitse of-fensief in Polen besprak.

I would like to know if there is a fast way to get rid of those word breaks. There is no online tool that does the trick. I am slightly familiar with python, so solutions involving python could be welcome. Perhaps an idea is to use a regular expression for the purpose of removing al '-' characters that are at the end of the line in a txt-file?

This is what I tried, using the comments below:

```
import re

with open('pdf_test.txt','r+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    text = f.read()
    for line in text:
       if line.endswith('-'):
          line = re.sub('-',' ',line)
          f.seek(0)
          f.write(line)
          f.truncate()
```

However, this doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is efficient but you could use `replace`:

```
text.replace('- ','')
```

or with `regex`:

```
import re
with open('pdf_test.txt','r+') as f:
    text = f.read()
    text = re.sub('- ','',text)
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(text)
    f.truncate()
```

But those two ways will replace every such character('- ') they find, not only in the end of the sentence. The good thing is that I don't think you can find the '- ' in a normal text.

**Update**

Well, after seeing your comments I guess that the text looks like this:

```
De reden van alle beroering was niet moeilijk te raden. Adri-
aan bleef even staan bij een gezelschap jongerejaars om te ho-
ren welke uitkomst de discussie kreeg. Maar terwijl hij stond te luisteren naar 
meningen over de acute kwestie Nieuw-Gui-
nea, overviel hem de herinnering aan een zonovergoten mid-
dag begin september 1939 in dezelfde hal toen hij, student gene-
eskunde, met jaargenoten het zojuist ontketende Duitse of-
fensief in Polen besprak.
```

(I code-formate to be able to keep the format of it...)

In this case if you just want to replace all the '-' with '' that are in the end of each line you could do:

```
import re
with open('pdf_test.txt','r+') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0)
    for line in lines:
        if line[-2]=='-':
            line = re.sub('-','',line)   
        f.write(line)
```

The `.endswith('-')` will not work neither in this case, cause the last character of each line is the `\n`, so there will be no actual change to the original text - that is why I used the `line[-2]` to check for the '-' character.

Comment: The problem is that you do find '-' in a normal Dutch text. With regards to the example I used: in 'Nieuw-Gui- nea' the first  '-' belongs there, but the second '-' has to be removed.

Comment: @RoelSmeets, yes that is why is used '- ' instead of '-' .If you try `'Nieuw-Gui- nea'.replace('- ','')` this will give as result: 'Nieuw-Guinea' which is what you described.

Comment: sorry I did not notice that difference. I will look into it!

Comment: @RoelSmeets, I just don't know how efficient this would be for large txt files...

Comment: I get a TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object when I do the following on the command line. import re with open ('pdf_test.txt') as text: re.sub('- ',' ',text)

Comment: @RoelSmeets, You get that error cause you don't actually read the file just open it, give a try with the updated version of the answer...

Comment: The updated version of the answer does not work, though... Can't seem to understand why.

Comment: Perhaps it has to be something like: for line in text: if line endswith '-  ': text.replace('- ','')  and write that content to a new document?

Comment: However, this does do anything: with open('pdf_test.txt','r+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    text = f.readlines()
    for line in text:
     if line.endswith('-'):
      line = re.sub('-','',text)
      f.seek(0)
      f.write(text)
      f.truncate()

Comment: @RoelSmeets, hm..,for me it worked fine for the text you provided in your post - so when you say it doesn't work you mean you get an error and if yes what kind of error? also have in mind that in the answer we overwrite the original file with the correct results so just check to see if the contents of the file after you exec the script must have changed - also we don't really need to read the file line per line, we just read all its contents and apply the changes just once...

Comment: I do not get an error, the execution of the script is without errors. The problem is that the original file is not changed by the correct results. The reason that I put the for loop in my updated version of my post is that it doesn't work after all to just replace the '- ' with ' ' . It is really only about the '-' at the end of each lines. So I don't get  why the original file is not overwritten with the correct results – do you?

Comment: @RoelSmeets, that the '-' is in the end of the line in the pdf doesn't mean that it is going to be in the end of each line in the .txt (e.g. 'Adri- aan' is not in the end of the line) - so the `.endswith` is not going to work. To catch the case of replacing only the '-' that appear to be in the end of the lines we use '- ' instead of '-'. Another mistake in your code(in the above comments) is that you are using `f.write(text)` instead of `f.write(line)` - It should be also `line = re.sub('-','',line)`. But again I don't think that the readlines approach will work for the reason I mentioned.

Comment: Well, it appears I made a mistake. The example text I submitted in my post had no '- ' after all, only '-'. I had tried to make the text look like the txt-file that has been converted from pdf. You don't see it in my post, but when I convert the pdf tot a txt-file the '-' IS at the end of the line. So the .endswith should work, shouldn't it?. I updated my code (see my post), but when I run it now, the output is pdf_test.txt completely empty, without any text. Do you have a suggestion as to what goes wrong?

Comment: @RoelSmeets, just updated the answer, check now to see if it works - I've explained also the `endswith` approach in this case also!

Answer (score 0):

PDFMiner is an option for you , and [this is an example](https://github.com/dpapathanasiou/pdfminer-layout-scanner/blob/master/layout_scanner.py) to extract text from PDF pages.

For your purposes, you'd have to alter line 176 to

```
' '.join(text_content)
```

which will remove the line breaks.

Comment: Thanx, that might work. I suppose you mean ' '.join(text_content) without the first ` ?

Comment: Ah, that was a typo when I changed the formatting of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I have a PHP code that do that, i don't know to much of Python, but i think would be like this:

```
import re

text = re.sub(r"(-|–)(\n+)", "", text)
```

But i think that some PDF files when converted to text thay lose that "-" character, in this case i have no idea how to work around that.